# Cannot Create Database Diagram In SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and I'm trying to create a database diagram for a DB I created. I created the DB on the local SQL server an when I try to create a new database diagram it doesn't let me. It just gives me the option:

"Working with SQL Server 2005 diagrams".

It does not give me any option to create a new database diagram. It is strange though as I also connected to another SQL Server 2005 instance on our internal network and I have the option to create database diagram on that server.

Any help is appreciated.

Cian

Comment: What edition(s) of SQL are you using? Perhaps MSDE doesn't support them?

Comment: SQL comes in varrying *editions* -- Enterprise, Standard, Developer, and a handful of even more obscure flavors. Run `PRINT @@Version` to check a given instance

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need a certain privilege (db-owner?) to create diagrams.

Could that be the problem?